# ¿Como puedo mover el principio de un tiro parabolico hacia la derecha?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Soy un principiante en C++ y tengo una duda.
Nos dejaron un ejercicio de choque entre proyectiles de tiro parabólico, Instrucciones:

Crear un programa donde existen 2 cañones uno se dispara a una velocidad inicial v1 y un angulo teta, otro se dispara a una velocidad inicial v2 y angulo alfa. los 2 cañones están separados por una distancia d. todos los datos los da el usuario.

Los proyectiles son cuadrados de 10 cm en incrementos de tiempo de 0.001 segundos diga:

en que tiempo chocan, en que tiempo pasa uno encima del otro o si no se impactan nunca los proyectiles.

Solo quiero saber como podría mover el segundo tiro para que empiece desde el final de la distancia y se pueda hacer el calculo. les adjunto lo que llevo:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
const float gravedad = -9.81;
const float Pi = 3.14159;

int main() {
    float   t = 0, Vix1, Vix2, Viy1, Viy2, h1 = 0, h2 = 0, DistanciaP;
    int     v1, v2, alfa, teta, d;

    cout << "Dame la velocidad del canion 1\n";
    cin >> v1;
    cout << "Dame el angulo del canion 1\n";
    cin >> alfa;
    cout << "Dame la velocidad del canion 2\n";
    cin >> v2;
    cout << "Dame el angulo del canion 2\n";
    cin >> teta;
    cout << "Dame la distancia que los separa\n";
    cin >> d;
    teta = 180 - teta;
    Vix1 = v1 * cos(alfa * Pi / 180);
    Vix2 = v2 * cos(teta * Pi / 180);
    Viy1 = v1 * sin(alfa * Pi / 180);
    Viy2 = v2 * sin(teta * Pi / 180);
    do {
        t = t + 0.001;
        h1 = Viy1 * t + 0.5 * gravedad * pow(t, 2);
        h2 = Viy2 * t + 0.5 * gravedad * pow(t, 2);
        DistanciaP = d - ((v1 * t) + (v2 * t));
    } while (DistanciaP > 0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: No quiero esto]

[image: Quiero esto]

Solo me quedan 2 horas para entregar el trabajo, Espero uno de ustedes pueda resolver mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerdalo como vectores.

Necesitas 2 distancias en este caso, una distancia para el proyectil 1, que parte en 0 y una distancia para el proyectil 2 que parte en "d" (Que es la distancia que los separa) y que vaya disminuyendo con el desplazamiento propio del proyectil (d2 = d-vx2*t)

Esto te facilita que, por ejemplo, en el tiempo 0, el proyectil 1 este ubicado en 0 y el proyectil 2 este ubicado en 20 -por ejemplo- luego en esos incrementos de tiempo, por ejemplo 5s después, el proyectil 1 con una velocidad = v1 angulo alfa = alfa y un tiempo t= 5s se desplace 5mts (es un ejemplo tomando solo el desplazamiento), se ubique en d1=5... así mismo el proyectil 2 con una velocidad = v2 angulo teta = teta y tiempo t=5s se desplace 6mts es decir este en un punto d2 = 20 - 6 = 14 y en t=6 d2 = 20 - 7 = 13 y sucesivamente, Así fuerzas al vector de desplazamiento ir hacia atrás partiendo del punto que los separa.

Ya después evalúas cuando d1 = d2 que pasa, es decir si las h son iguales se chocan, si son diferentes pasa uno por arriba y así, no ahondo en esto porque solo pediste lo de las posiciones.

Espero me comprendas y te sirva, Saludos.